# Toolbar cannot be cast

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-toolbar

I'm trying to make in chat app after I click on every user to open the message activity for every user but i'm using androidx and the Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar.I want to show me only a text with the username.I take the id "username1" from my cardview.I use the username1 in another xml for a class where all my users appear.Here is my database:

[image]

The message activity:

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView username;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_message );
       TabLayout appBarLayout=findViewById ( R.id.tab_2);



            username=findViewById ( R.id.username1 );

            intent=getIntent ();
            String userid=intent.getStringExtra ( "userid" );
            fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
            reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child ( "FIRST NAME");
            reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user=dataSnapshot.getValue (User.class);
                    username.setText ( user.getFirstName () );

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );
        }


    }
```

The xml for message activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MessageActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4CAF50" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What shows me in debugger:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sportsbuddy, PID: 858
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.sportsbuddy.User.getFirstName()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sportsbuddy.MessageActivity$1.onDataChange(MessageActivity.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

The user class:

```
public class User {
   public String mfirstName;
    public String msecondname;
    public String muid;
    public String memail;
    public User(){

    }



    public User (String firstName, String secondName, String uid, String email) {
        this.mfirstName = firstName;
        this.msecondname = secondName;
        this.muid=uid;
        this.memail=email;
    }

    public User (String firstName, String secondName) {
    }
@PropertyName ( "FIRST NAME" )
    public String getFirstName () {
        return mfirstName;
    }
    @PropertyName ("SECOND NAME" )
    public String getSecondName () {
        return msecondname;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "Uid" )
    public String getUid () {
        return muid;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "E-MAIL" )
    public String getEmail () {
        return memail;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "FIRST NAME" )
    public void setFirstName (String firstName) {
        this.mfirstName = firstName;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "SECOND NAME" )
    public void setSecondName (String secondName) {
        this.msecondname = secondName;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "Uid" )
    public void setUid (String uid) {
        this.muid = uid;
    }
    @PropertyName ( "E-MAIL" )
    public void setEmail (String email) {
        this.memail = email;
    }
}
```

I expect to show me an empty activity for every user instead of app to crahs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up `reference` like this:

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child ( "FIRST NAME");
```

So this points to `/users/FIRST NAME`, which doesn't exist in your JSON. That means your `dataSnapshot` will be empty.

My guess is that you want to refer to the node for the current user, which you do with:

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child (userid);
```

Or

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child (fuser.getUid());
```

Comment: I have a list of users and when i click on an user it opens me an activity for message and I want to show their first name from the database. and i only put for their first name to appear in the activity which shows me every user. Like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJkzVc2D0iY&list=PLzLFqCABnRQftQQETzoVMuteXzNiXmnj8&index=6

Comment: I found the problem but it shows me the first name of the current user,not the user i want to talk with.

Comment: If you want to look up the name of another user, you'll need to know **their** UID and put it into `getReference ("users").child (theOtherUid);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of toolbar, it's a problem of database request. The error is at this line

```
User user=dataSnapshot.getValue (User.class);
```

User is null.

Comment: And what should I do ?

Comment: check if the database is well filled, check what does exactly dataSnapshot.getValue, maybe use an ORM to make the work with database easier...